# rollup ignores group by having constraint

Tags: mysql, group-by, having, rollup

```
+----+-------+-------+
| id | style | color |
+----+-------+-------+
|  1 |     1 | red   |
|  2 |     1 | blue  |
|  3 |     2 | red   |
|  4 |     2 | blue  |
|  5 |     2 | green |
|  6 |     3 | blue  |
+----+-------+-------+
```

The query:

```
SELECT style, COUNT(*) as count from t GROUP BY style WITH ROLLUP HAVING count > 1;
```

produces:

```
+-------+-------+
| style | count |
+-------+-------+
|     1 |     2 |
|     2 |     3 |
|  NULL |     6 |
+-------+-------+
```

What do I have to do to get WITH ROLLUP to sum only those counts meeting the HAVING requirement?  That is, I'd like to see '5' for count in the rollup row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was totally convoluted and nasty but I got it

```
SELECT style,COUNT(1) as count
FROM t
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT t1.style as count
    FROM
    (
        SELECT style from t GROUP BY style HAVING count(*) = 1
    ) t1 WHERE t.style = t1.style
)
GROUP BY style
WITH ROLLUP;
```

Here is the sample data from the question:

```
drop database if exists rollup_test;
create database rollup_test;
use rollup_test
create table t (id int not null auto_increment,
style int,color varchar(10),primary key (id));
insert into t (style,color) values
(1,'red'),(1,'blue'),(2,'red'),
(2,'blue'),(2,'green'),(3,'blue');
select * from t;
```

Here it is loaded:

```
mysql> drop database if exists rollup_test;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> create database rollup_test;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> use rollup_test
Database changed
mysql> create table t (id int not null auto_increment,
    -> style int,color varchar(10),primary key (id));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.10 sec)

mysql> insert into t (style,color) values
    -> (1,'red'),(1,'blue'),(2,'red'),
    -> (2,'blue'),(2,'green'),(3,'blue');
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from t;
+----+-------+-------+
| id | style | color |
+----+-------+-------+
|  1 |     1 | red   |
|  2 |     1 | blue  |
|  3 |     2 | red   |
|  4 |     2 | blue  |
|  5 |     2 | green |
|  6 |     3 | blue  |
+----+-------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Here is the query's result:

```
mysql> SELECT style,COUNT(1) as count
    -> FROM t
    -> WHERE NOT EXISTS
    -> (
    ->     SELECT t1.style as count
    ->     FROM
    ->     (
    ->         SELECT style from t GROUP BY style HAVING count(*) = 1
    ->     ) t1 WHERE t.style = t1.style
    -> )
    -> GROUP BY style
    -> WITH ROLLUP;
+-------+-------+
| style | count |
+-------+-------+
|     1 |     2 |
|     2 |     3 |
|  NULL |     5 |
+-------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

The problem is that `WITH ROLLUP` is evaluated before `HAVING`. I arranged the query in such a way that `WITH ROLLUP` was done last.

Mission Accomplished !!!